# Regular Expressions for Country Name

Tags: php, regex

I have a requirement to create a validation for the presence of a Country Name.  I want to ensure that the item receives at least two Alpha Characters.  I have a chunk of code now `/^[a-zA-Z ]\{2,\}*\z/` The problem is that it doesn't work, for some reason.  It refuses to accept any proper word, at least two characters long.  I think the `{2,\}` is the culprit.  I am not sure how to get this working.  I understand the alpha test but the minimum two characters eludes me.  By the way I don't really care about the correctness of the entry only that it be at least two 'alpha characters long'.
Thanks...
Robert

Comment: Can you post some example data, which of you expect to match and which you don't

Comment: I need only one country (canada, ca) but for information I will accept what is posted but not less that two Alpha characters, that's all. It is an online app which has not gone live as yet.  Thank you for your offer of help:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

works fine - see http://regex101.com/r/wD3zK9

You don't need to escape the brackets - in fact, if you do they lose their "special meaning".

Comment: I tried that and I received an error message.--->An error occurred in script register.php' on line 48: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '{' <--- I am using a function called preg_match() used by Larry Ullman author of PHP 6 and MySql 5.  It uses the Regular Expression as a parameter.  I am using PHP 5.4.24. Other regexes work but I am not sure why it howls at the '{' ??

Comment: Yes.  I missed the ^ works now.  Thank you people so much.  That was so fast. Robert

Comment: @user3386373 can u paste the correct regex?

Answer (score 4):

I created a giant regex which contain all country codes (2 and 3 characters)

```
^(AF|AX|AL|DZ|AS|AD|AO|AI|AQ|AG|AR|AM|AW|AU|AT|AZ|BS|BH|BD|BB|BY|BE|BZ|BJ|BM|BT|BO|BQ|BA|BW|BV|BR|IO|BN|BG|BF|BI|KH|CM|CA|CV|KY|CF|TD|CL|CN|CX|CC|CO|KM|CG|CD|CK|CR|CI|HR|CU|CW|CY|CZ|DK|DJ|DM|DO|EC|EG|SV|GQ|ER|EE|ET|FK|FO|FJ|FI|FR|GF|PF|TF|GA|GM|GE|DE|GH|GI|GR|GL|GD|GP|GU|GT|GG|GN|GW|GY|HT|HM|VA|HN|HK|HU|IS|IN|ID|IR|IQ|IE|IM|IL|IT|JM|JP|JE|JO|KZ|KE|KI|KP|KR|KW|KG|LA|LV|LB|LS|LR|LY|LI|LT|LU|MO|MK|MG|MW|MY|MV|ML|MT|MH|MQ|MR|MU|YT|MX|FM|MD|MC|MN|ME|MS|MA|MZ|MM|NA|NR|NP|NL|NC|NZ|NI|NE|NG|NU|NF|MP|NO|OM|PK|PW|PS|PA|PG|PY|PE|PH|PN|PL|PT|PR|QA|RE|RO|RU|RW|BL|SH|KN|LC|MF|PM|VC|WS|SM|ST|SA|SN|RS|SC|SL|SG|SX|SK|SI|SB|SO|ZA|GS|SS|ES|LK|SD|SR|SJ|SZ|SE|CH|SY|TW|TJ|TZ|TH|TL|TG|TK|TO|TT|TN|TR|TM|TC|TV|UG|UA|AE|GB|US|UM|UY|UZ|VU|VE|VN|VG|VI|WF|EH|YE|ZM|ZW|AFG|ALB|DZA|ASM|AND|AGO|AIA|ATA|ATG|ARG|ARM|ABW|AUS|AUT|AZE|BHS|BHR|BGD|BRB|BLR|BEL|BLZ|BEN|BMU|BTN|BOL|BIH|BWA|BVT|BRA|IOT|VGB|BRN|BGR|BFA|BDI|KHM|CMR|CAN|CPV|CYM|CAF|TCD|CHL|CHN|CXR|CCK|COL|COM|COD|COG|COK|CRI|CIV|CUB|CYP|CZE|DNK|DJI|DMA|DOM|ECU|EGY|SLV|GNQ|ERI|EST|ETH|FRO|FLK|FJI|FIN|FRA|GUF|PYF|ATF|GAB|GMB|GEO|DEU|GHA|GIB|GRC|GRL|GRD|GLP|GUM|GTM|GIN|GNB|GUY|HTI|HMD|VAT|HND|HKG|HRV|HUN|ISL|IND|IDN|IRN|IRQ|IRL|ISR|ITA|JAM|JPN|JOR|KAZ|KEN|KIR|PRK|KOR|KWT|KGZ|LAO|LVA|LBN|LSO|LBR|LBY|LIE|LTU|LUX|MAC|MKD|MDG|MWI|MYS|MDV|MLI|MLT|MHL|MTQ|MRT|MUS|MYT|MEX|FSM|MDA|MCO|MNG|MSR|MAR|MOZ|MMR|NAM|NRU|NPL|ANT|NLD|NCL|NZL|NIC|NER|NGA|NIU|NFK|MNP|NOR|OMN|PAK|PLW|PSE|PAN|PNG|PRY|PER|PHL|PCN|POL|PRT|PRI|QAT|REU|ROU|RUS|RWA|SHN|KNA|LCA|SPM|VCT|WSM|SMR|STP|SAU|SEN|SCG|SYC|SLE|SGP|SVK|SVN|SLB|SOM|ZAF|SGS|ESP|LKA|SDN|SUR|SJM|SWZ|SWE|CHE|SYR|TWN|TJK|TZA|THA|TLS|TGO|TKL|TON|TTO|TUN|TUR|TKM|TCA|TUV|VIR|UGA|UKR|ARE|GBR|UMI|USA|URY|UZB|VUT|VEN|VNM|WLF|ESH|YEM|ZMB|ZWE)$
```